# create archive of temp directory and write it to the temp directory

Tags: python, shutil

I am trying to create an archive of a temporary directory and place that archive in the temporary directory when complete. This way, I can delete the entire directory after the request in my web app is complete.

Right now, when the process is complete, the archive also contains the `OutputArchive.zip` file in it. How can I write the `OutputArchive.zip` to the `temp_dir` without zipping itself?

**Code**

```
# zip all contents of this
temp_dir = r'E:\webapps\geodata-dev\data\tmpws55et'

# place the OutputArchive.zip in the above directory without zipping itself
shutil.make_archive(os.path.join(temp_dir, 'OutputArchive'), 'zip', temp_dir)
```

Comment: Why don't you create `OutputArchive.zip ` in `E:\webapps\geodata-dev\data` and move it in `temp_dir` once it's finished ?

Comment: @Antikhippe its a web app and i assume that could cause a write conflict on multiple simultaneous requests.